# Trdion Sites pagination in Graphql query to get total records count

Tags: graphql, tridion-sites, pca

I am using cursor for pagination in Graphql query, I want to also get total records count with the response, How can I achieve?

```
query GenericQuery {
    items(
        filter: {publicationIds: 1, itemTypes: [COMPONENT], schema: {id: 112233}}
        first: 3
        after: "Mw=="
    ) {
        edges {
            node {
                itemId
                title
                lastPublishDate
                itemType
                ... on Component {
                    title
                    multiMedia
                    content(renderContent: true) {
                        ... on UntypedContent {
                            data
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            cursor
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total count field is not available.

One workaround is to use a separate query to get the total count.

You can execute a second query with the same filter criteria but without the pagination arguments (e.g., first, after, etc.), and then retrieve the total count from the response.